# Wie sagt man "Company's name" auf Deutsch?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> Ich arbeite als Staatsanwalt u. mein Betriebsname heißt Habas and
>   Associates

Ich bin mir unsicher über das Wort *Betriebsname*. Wie sagt man "Company's Name" auf Hochdeutsch? Im Wörterbuch steht, dass das Präfix dafür "Betriebs-" heißt. Also bin ich unsicher, ob dieses Wort richtig ist.

Comment: This isn't directly related to the question, but a *Staatsanwalt* cannot work at a private practice; they work for the government. A *Rechtsanwalt* works for a private practice (well actually lots of other kinds of attorneys work for private practices too)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- DE: Üblicherweise würde man **Firmenname** sagen/schreiben.
- EN: Usually you'd use (say/write) **Firmenname**.

I don't know about your jurisdiction, but I think *Staatsanwalt* which *can* be translated as *attorney* but is usually translated as *prosecutor* or *federal prosecutor* or even *state attorney* is a different thing entirely. In Germany a Staatsanwalt wouldn't have his own law firm (Kanzlei/Anwaltskanzlei), see below.

---

**However**, in case of an attorney (most likely Anwalt, Rechtsanwalt in your context, not Staatsanwalt) it would be:

> Ich arbeite als *Anwalt* und meine *Kanzlei* heißt Habas and Associates

- *Anwalt* could also be *Rechtsanwalt*
- *Kanzlei* could also be *Anwaltskanzlei* or *Rechtsanwaltskanzlei*

"Eingedeutscht":

> Ich arbeite als *Anwalt* und meine *Kanzlei* heißt Habas und Partner

or

> Ich arbeite als *Anwalt* und meine *Kanzlei* heißt Habas & Partner

But as pointed out in a comment to this answer, it sounds better to say

> Ich arbeite als *Anwalt* bei/in der *Kanzlei* Habas & Partner

Conclusion: I think you attempted a literal translation of "law firm" here ... which doesn't work well.

Comment: When can I use the prefix "Betriebs-" ??

Comment: @DerPolyglott33: there are loads of cases where you can use it. But even if it was applicable like, say, for a carpentry (unless you use the specific term "Schreinerei"), you'd say "Name des Betriebs" instead of "Betriebsname". "Betriebs-" can even be used outside the scope of referring to a firm, like it does in "Betriebsrat" (a staff association) or "Betriebsprüfung" (roughly an IRS investigation). One such example would be "Betriebssystem" (operating system). It's not suitable for law firms, though :)

Comment: @Vogel612: agreed, that sounds also good. Will add it in for future readers.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the accepted answer suggests something that is wrong. A companies name is simply "Firma". That is "legal name of the business" is the true meaning of the word. Here is a citation from Wikipedia:

> Eine Firma (abgekürzt: Fa.; von lat. firmare „beglaubigen, befestigen“) ist der Name, unter dem ein Kaufmann seine Geschäfte betreibt, seine Unterschriften leistet und unter dem er klagen und verklagt werden kann.

From this, it is also apparent, why we cannot use "Firma" for a law firm, at least not in Germany, as an attorney is simply not a merchant.

To be sure, we can use the word "Firma" figuratively, like in

> Ich gehe in die Firma.

but this should not let us forget the literal meaning. Because, when you say "Firmenname", this is then non-sensical "name of the name of a business".

Comment: Fortunately, though, the accepted answer answers the *actual question* in the context (law firm). Btw: so it's okay to say "die Firma heißt ..." but not "der Firmenname ist ..."? Are you kidding? You must be. I mean you have valid points, but a.) Wikipedia is not *the* reference point for everything and b.) if it was for literal meaning you should rethink *every* use of "komisch", "seltsam" and "merkwürdig" in each respective situation. Do you?

Comment: @0xC0000022L "die Firma ist ..." would be correct, though "die Firma heißt" is probably acceptable as figurative meaning. You are right that Wikipedia is not the end of all wisdom, but in this case, the definition is simply correct. I suggest that everyone who says "Firmenname" will signal lack of education, but I could be wrong, of course. Anyway, things and their names are confused far too often, so just don't.

Comment: @0xC0000022L There are other sources besides Wikipedia, for example the relevant paragraphs of GmbHG (and similarly for other forms, but I only have that at hand). *Firma* is - legally and perhaps contrary to everyday use - the name and not the institution or building.

Comment: Yes, there are other sources, [the Duden for example](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Firma) states (meaning 1a) that »Firma« means “company”, which, I assume, most German native speakers will agree with.

Answer (score 0):

Schön ausgedrückt würde man sagen:
Ich arbeite als Rechtsanwalt für die (oder "in der") Kanzlei Habas und Kollegen.

Comment: Das wurde bereits von den anderen Antworten abgedeckt, nur dass du "Partner" durch "Kollegen" ausgetauscht hast.